# What is the easiest way to deploy multiple web applications within one solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I am adding an ecommerce section to an existing web application using NopCommerce (open source ecommerce package).  Since the ecommerce section is logically different and Nop is built on MVC and my application is web forms I am keeping everything separate in my solution.  When debugging locally I have all of the projects setup to use iis so I am able to debug them as a whole.  All this seems to be setup good but when I go to publish the site I have to publish the three web apps (my app, nop, nop admin) separately.  Is there something in vs2010 that I can use to publish all three applications at once?  I guess it isn;t really that big of a deal but I would like to set things up correctly so any ideas, comments, or references would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: What kind of publish method are you using? I usually use the "to filesystem" method and manually move the files over to my web server, I just recently started using FTP to deploy to a godaddy server and that works pretty well but I only currently have one project in my solution.

Comment: 4 years later I find myself using Microsoft Release Management https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/release-management-vs.aspx

Comment: holy moses, how far we've come in 4 years :) I use web deploy and publish profiles quite a bit, and target different build configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible with Visual Studio environment but you can run the command line tool - [aspnet_compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) from within the batch file.

Found an interesting blog-posts:

1. [Web Deployment Made Awesome: If You're Using XCopy, You're Doing It Wrong](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx)
2. [How To Create an ASP.NET Application from Multiple Projects for Team Development](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307467)
3. [VS 2005 Web Deployment Projects](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx)
4. [ASP.NET Deployment Content Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386521.aspx)
5. [How to publish an entire solution as a single Setup file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/90fa0511-34d4-4713-b763-6a2fc423b06a)